# How to convert unciode to list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, json

**I want to convert the json format to a table .I wanted the json format to be  a "list of dic",but it is in "unicode" format. 
If it is in "list of dict",then i can easily convert it to a table**

```
import json
import requests
url = "http://localhost:8080/api/vi/empdata"
headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "72c97887-727e-ae9e-36ed-182f725f"
    }
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
data = response.text
print(data)
for x in data:
  print(x)
```

**print(data) gives the following output:**

```
[{"name": "Aarush", "address": "Yoyager"}, {"name": "Sanju", "address": 
"Victor"}, {"name": "Yara", "address": "Victor"}, {"name": "Zara", 
"address": "Voyager"}]
```

**print(x) gives the follwing output:**

```
[
{
"
n
a
m
e
"
:

"
A
a
r
u
s
h
"
,

"
a
d
d
r
e
s
s
"
:

"
Y
o
y
a
g
e
r
"
}
,

{
......goes on
```

**I wanted the output of print(x) to be:**

```
{'name': 'Aarush', 'address': 'Yoyager'}
{'name': 'Sanju', 'address': 'Victor'}
{'name': 'Yara', 'address': 'Victor'}
{'name': 'Zara', 'address': 'Voyager'}
```

Comment: pd.DataFrame(x) will solve the problem

Comment: print(data) is in unicode.....  i want print(data) to be list of dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of requests, you can use:

```
data = response.json()
```

or

```
import json
...
data = json.loads(response.text)
```